# Problem binding gradient background color uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im trying to bind a gradients to variables in a uwp app. Y tried binding it with a background and there was zero problem. But when I tried to binding it to the gradient in the xaml it looks trasnparent. Any idea why?

Here is in the xaml

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Gradient0}" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Gradient1}" Offset="0.210" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Gradient2}" Offset="0.760" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="{Binding Gradient3}" Offset="0.900" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
```

These are my variables:

```
private Brush Gradient0;
public Brush Gradient0 { get => Gradient0; set { Gradient0 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient0)); } }

private Brush Gradient1;
public Brush Gradient1{ get => Gradient1; set { Gradient1= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient1)); } }

private Brush Gradient2;
public Brush Gradient2{ get => Gradient2; set { Gradient2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient2)); } }

private Brush Gradient3;
public Brush Gradient3{ get => Gradient3; set { Gradient3= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient3)); } }
```

I tried using the some of the gradients brushes as a flat background color and it worked, but as a gradient it doesn´t

This is how the button looks with the gradient binded

[image]

This is how it looks if I use Gradient0 value as binded background color

[image]

Comment: Please share Gradient0 - Gradient3 value you have used .

Comment: Did you try using Color instead of Brush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem binding gradient background color uwp

During the testing, the problem is the Color property can't be set `Brush` directly, you need replace the type of Gradient with Color for the ViewModdel class.

**For Example**

```
public class HomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color _gradient0;
    public Color Gradient0 { get => _gradient0; set { _gradient0 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient0)); } }

    private Color _gradient1;
    public Color Gradient1 { get => _gradient1; set { _gradient1 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient1)); } }

    private Color _gradient2;
    public Color Gradient2 { get => _gradient2; set { _gradient2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient2)); } }

    private Color _gradient3;

    public Color Gradient3 { get => _gradient3; set { _gradient3 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Gradient3)); } }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**Usgae**

```
public HomePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //var viewmodel = new HomeViewModel()
    //{
    //    Gradient0 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    //    Gradient1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue),
    //    Gradient2 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCyan),
    //    Gradient3 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Beige)
    //};

    var viewmodel = new HomeViewModel()
    {
        Gradient0 = Colors.Red,
        Gradient1 = Colors.LightBlue,
        Gradient2 = Colors.LightCyan,
        Gradient3 = Colors.Beige
    };

    this.DataContext = viewmodel;
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks! Any idea why I can use a brush as a background color when using property Background but I cant when is a Gradient?

Comment: It's by design, the  property is [color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.gradientstop.color?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_GradientStop_Color) type but not SolidColorBrush.